# Add Input from UITextField to Array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'll try to preface this as clearly as possible. I have a simple .plist stored in the Documents folder with two different keys. I'm using an AlertView UITextField to receive user input which should be added to the correct key. Using the `setObject:forKey` returns `NSMutableArray` may not respond to `setObject:forKey`. With my current code below I can write to my .plist but the problem is it's changed from a Dictionary to a simple Array. How would I implement a `writeToFile` for a specific key with this setup? Or on the flip side, am I approaching this from the wrong direction?

In my h

```
@interface RootViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

UINavigationBar *navBar;
UITableView *myTable;
NSMutableArray *info;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *info;


@end
```

And in my m. Yes this is being done without the use of IB completely in code

```
//************* Add New Cell To TableView When OK is Chosen

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

 UITextField *newDevice = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"newDevice - %@",newDevice.text);

  if (alertView.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 1){

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stuff.plist"];


  [self.info writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

  [myTable reloadData]
```

**UPDATE**

A little insight on how I've managed to put myself into this situation

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stuff.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.info = [dict objectForKey:@"Area"];
```

Above code is how I've managed to populate my TableView so I'm possibly going about this wrong. `NSMutableDictionary` Doesn't respond to `removeObjectAtIndexPath` and I'd like to be able to delete a cell from my TableView.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: if you wan't to keep a dictionary, use `NSDictionary` for `info` instead of `NSMutableArray`

Comment: `setObject:forKey:` is a method of `NSMutableDictionary`, not `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: This: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary.html and this: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray.html

Comment: This forum has been great to help learn a few things but it seems lately it's turned into a bunch of know nothing DESIGNERS instead of helpful programmers or actual developers. The problem with NSMutableDictionary is that it doesn't respond to removeObjectAtIndexPath. So yes I've gotten myself into a confused situation but I've come here for help, which is a moot cause :( I'm aware there is a difference but then again I've managed to declare my array and still look for a key within it to populate my TableView which tells me what I'm looking to do here is still within the limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stuff.plist"];
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 


 UITextField *newDevice = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"newDevice - %@",newDevice.text);

  if (alertView.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 1){


 NSMutableArray *existing = dictionary[@"Area"];
[existing addObject:newDevice.text];
[dictionary setObject:existing forKey:@"Area"];
[dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[self.info addObject:newDevice.text];
[myTable reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to update the key `Area` in the property list, but keep other properties unchanged.

To accomplish this, keep the dictionary representation around, e.g.,

```
NSMutableArray *info;
NSMutableDictionary *dict; // add instance variable
```

and

```
dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; // remove local variable
```

Then, when writing:

```
[dict setObject:info forKey:@"Area"];
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

(You could also make `dict` a property, and you could remove the `info` variable, instead implementing its accessors to work on the key in the dictionary.)

Comment: this points me in a direction at least. Your version doesn't write to file but with a little manipulation Im able to write to file, under appropriate key. The problem I have is it now deletes the <array> and <array/> values rendering the plist unreadable. I've tried a couple iterations all producing the same result. Changing `info` to `newDevice.text` produced the best result yet still removed the <array> values

Comment: You assumption is half correct, I'd like to add to the `Area` in the property list. From the feel of it I'll have to resort to multiple NSArrays when a NSDictionary is really more efficient @Arkku

Comment: @Chilly The `writeToFile:atomically:` call does write the dictionary to file. As for multiple `NSArrays` vs `NSDictionary`, I really don't see what you're getting at; you can store an arbitrary number of arrays as values in a single dictionary, and then write that dictionary to a plist.